# inner div not pushing to 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5. However I don't think this issue is related to Foundation anyway. I have a outer `div` with `height: auto;` One of the inner `div` I'm trying to make `height: 100%` to reach till footer. But that doesn't work. Currently there is a huge gap between the sitemap `div` and footer.

You can refer to this link: http://vani.valse.com.my/schone_lightings/productlisting.html

My HTML:

```
!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
 <!--header ends-->

    <!--body starts-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns"><!-- I want to make this height:100%;-->
        <div class="container">
            menu 1
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            menu 2
        </div>

       <div class="container">
        content
       </div>       

        <div class="container">
            site map
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
   <!--body ends-->

   <!--footer starts-->
   <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns footer">
    Footer

   </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
<!--footer ends-->
```

My CSS:

```
body
{
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   background-image:url('../img/body-bg.jpg');
}

.row
{
   max-width: 85%;
   height:100%;

   background-color:#fff;
   opacity:0.9;
   filter:alpha(opacity=90)
}
.container
{
    border:1 px solid #000;
    width:85%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#ff0000;

}

div .container
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding:10px;
}
.footer
{
    background-color:#d2d1cf;
    padding:10px;   
}
```

Comment: your footer is outside .row so it will start when row is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying vertical height to your container which you want to be 100% height

for example

```
div {
height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a div's height to 100%, you need to set it's container's height to 100%

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubv6r7ew/)

Now if you just want your footer to stick to the bottom of the page, I would consider using an absolute position on it